# Image path issue in shared layout between pages

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm encountering an issue with my Next.js application where I have a shared layout component used across multiple pages. In the layout, I have an image in the navbar, and it displays correctly on the home page. However, when navigating to other pages, the image path seems to be affected by the current pathname, causing it to break.

Here's the problem in more detail:

Image source on the home page: "assets/logo.svg" transforms correctly to "http://localhost/assets/logo.svg".
When navigating to "/posts", the image source becomes "http://localhost/posts/assets/logo.svg" instead of "http://localhost/assets/logo.svg", resulting in a broken image.
I want the image source to remain consistent and not be affected by the current path. The image is located in the public folder, and its source should always be relative to the root of the public folder.

I tried to mess with the "next.config.js" file with no help

Comment: I guess your image (or img) tag needs to be updated to start with `/` -> `/assets/logo.svg`

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! It indeed worked, and I appreciate your quick response.

I must admit, it feels like such a simple fix, and I'm a bit embarrassed I didn't catch it earlier but I'm grateful for your help

Comment: It was my pleasure ;)

Answer (score 0):

easy fix :
just add an **' / '** first of all src. do `<img src="/img.svg" />` instead of `<img src="img.svg" />`